# How should I write my action creator to pass value from my component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

sorry in advance for the dumb question. I'm still learning javascript and sometime I have hard time writing simple operations.

I have the following action-creators :

```
export const fetchgadata = VIEW_ID => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST',
        isFetching:true,
        error:null
  });

return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gadata", {
  params: {
    id: VIEW_ID
  }
}).then(response => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
            isFetching: false,
            data: response.data.rows.map( ([x, y]) => ({ x, y }) )
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
            ype: 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE',
            isFetching:false,
            error:err
      });
      console.error("Failure: ", err);
    });
};

export function onSetTimeRange(timerange) {
 return {
        type: 'SET_TIME_RANGE',
        timerange
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is passing the `VIEW_ID` value to my axios param. So from here `... const fetchgadata = VIEW_ID => (dispatch) => { ...` to here `...return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gadata", { params: { id: VIEW_ID }
}).then(response => ...`

How should I wrote my code ?

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've done `VIEW_ID => (dispatch) =>` ... Do you pass dispatch to the exported function? You're effectively returning a function that returns another function, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @devJunk That's a pattern used with the `redux-thunk` middleware

Comment: @DrewSchuster thanks.

Comment: but does my issue is clear or not ? thanks :)